# JOOQ Foreign Key Conceptual Shortcoming?

Tags: java, jooq

Recently, I have started to use JOOQ (version 3.7.1) in my projects, 
however, I have already run into a problem which - for me - seems to be 
a shortcoming in the JOOQ implementation.

This shortcoming appears when performing a JOIN on a set of tables, 
in which one specific table appears more then once, for example a join 
of a table PERSON with itself (i.e. to find the data of the parents)..

The JOOQ generated PERSON class can be used more then once, using the 
Table.as(String name) method, however, the Foreign Keys returned by the getReferences() method simply return a list of references to the static Keys class. 
That way, joining a Person with the Address table, JOOQ doesn't have a way
to determine whether the primary Person, or the parent should be joined.

For that reason, it seems to me that the Foreign Key should always be combined with a reference to the specific table containing the Foreign Key (the referrer) and JOOQ, for example in the SelectQuery (SelectQueryImpl class) doesn't offer
that security.
The TableLike argument in the "addJoinOnKey" method refers to the table that is referred to, not the referrer.

Am i mistaken? Or is JOOQ really incapable of correctly handing queries 
in where a specific table is used more then once??
If it is, why isn't this fixed??

Best regards, looking forward to your comments.

Comment: There are design limitations in that area, and there had been recent fixes: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4637, https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2870. Apparently, there are still open issues. Would you mind posting some code that helps reproduce the issues you're experiencing? From the current question, it's a bit tricky to assess whether there is a shortcoming, a bug, or just a misunderstanding...

Comment: I wouldnt mind implementing some simple examples of where I think the shortcomings will appear, neither do I mind suggesting some design solution. I was just hoping i had missed a way to specify the foreign key different from referring to some foreign key as generated in the Keys class. If that alternative doesnt exist, there is already a logical shortcoming in for example the SelectQuery class (in cases where the referrer-table appears more then once), since its impossible to specify to which of (more then one) foreign keys we are referring. I will post simple good examples when i find them.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a shortcoming indeed, depending on how you look at the jOOQ API. There's an issue on the roadmap discussing the possibility of aliased tables returning aliased versions of constraint information:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5050

i.e.

```
// "MY_TABLE"."ID"
MY_TABLE.getPrimaryKey();

// "a"."ID"
MY_TABLE.as("a").getPrimaryKey();
```

In order to get the right set of columns from a table, you can always call:

```
MY_TABLE.as("a").fields(MY_TABLE.getPrimaryKey().getFieldsArray());
```

Whether there is also an additional bug (in addition to the above potential shortcoming) is hard to say from the current question. I'll update this answer once the question points to a concrete issue.

Comment: I agree very much with issue 5050. Whether or not there is an additional bug remains unclear to me too, but then again, what is the exact specification? Unfortunately, this issue is - for me - the reason to stick with implementing SQL.